# My screenmanager does not go back to my home screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Hi there I am a rookie in Python and Kivy. To practice I am trying to generate a new screen automatically when clicking a button of my new Kivy app. In the new screen, I generate two buttons. They should send me back to the home page, but when I click on them the following happens:

```
  File "~/screenmanager.py", line 1064, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "home_screen"
```

.

Can you check the code and explain what I am doing wrong, please?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior, Button
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout


class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = "img/spot.png"

    def on_release(self):
        sm = MyScreenManager()
        on_release = sm.change_screen(name="home_screen")
        self.source = "img/settings.png"

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

class MyGrids(GridLayout):

    def Grid_1x2():
        obj = GridLayout(cols=1)
        obj.add_widget(MyButton(
            #on_release = sm.change_screen(name="home_screen")
                    ))
        obj.add_widget(Button(
            text="World 4"
            #on_release = sm.change_screen(name="home_screen")
            ))
        return obj

class Homescreen(Screen):
    pass

class Newscreen(Screen):
    pass

class Settingscreen(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

#    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
#        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)


    def change_screen(self, name):
         self.current = name

    def new_screen(self):
        name="new_screen"
        mynewscreen = Newscreen(name=name)
        layout = MyGrids.Grid_1x2()
        mynewscreen.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(mynewscreen)
        self.current = name

GUI = Builder.load_file("main.kv")

class Main(App):

    def build(self):
        #print(self.root.ids)
        return GUI


Main().run()
```

My Main.kv is

```
#: include kv/homescreen.kv
#: include kv/settingscreen.kv


MyScreenManager:
    Homescreen:
        name: "home_screen"
        id: home_screen
    Settingscreen:
        name: "setting_screen"
        id: setting_screen
```

And my HomeScreen is:

```
<Homescreen>:

    FloatLayout:
        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                Rectangle:
                    # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"top":1, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .05

        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                Rectangle:
                    # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"top":0.95, "left": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .15

            GridLayout:
                rows: 1
                cols: 5
                pos_hint: {'left': .2}
                size_hint: 0.6, .15
                Label:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size
                ImageButton:
                    id: left
                    source: "img/arrow-left.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
                    on_release:
                        app.root.change_screen("setting_screen")

                Image:
                    source: "img/spot.png"

                ImageButton:
                    id: right
                    source: "img/arrow-right.png"
                    center_x: self.parent.center_x
                    center_y: self.parent.center_y
                    on_release:
                        app.root.change_screen("setting_screen")

                Label:
                    canvas.before:
                        Color:
                            rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                        Rectangle:
                            # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                            pos: self.pos
                            size: self.size

        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                Rectangle:
                    # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"top":0.8, "left": 1}
            size_hint:1, .2

        GridLayout:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0.99, 0.99, 0.99, 1
                Rectangle:
                    # self here refers to the widget i.e FloatLayout
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            cols: 1
            pos_hint: {"top":0.6, "left": 1}
            size_hint:1, .5

        Button:
            text: "New Screen"
            pos_hint: {"top":0.1, "left": 1}
            id: test
            size_hint:1, .1
            on_release:
                app.root.new_screen()
```

When I run the app, everything seems fine initially. It generates the new screen. However, I cannot go back to the homepage because the buttons generate a "No Screen with Name" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem

```
  File "~/screenmanager.py", line 1064, in get_screen
     raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "home_screen"
```

## Root Cause

In the method `on_release()`, it instantiated another instance of `MyScreenManager` which is different from the one instantiated in kv file. The screens, `"home_screen"` and `"settings_screen"` are not defined in this new instance of `MyScreenManager`. Due to this, your Kivy app threw the `ScreenManagerException`.

## Solution

Use the following in Python script:

1. [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) function to get an instance of your application
2. `root` which refers to the base widget/template in the current rule

### Snippets - py file

```
class MyButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):

    ...

    def on_release(self):
        App.get_running_app().root.current = "home_screen"
        self.source = "img/settings.png"
...
class MyGrids(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrids, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.add_widget(MyButton(
            # on_release = sm.change_screen(name="home_screen")
        ))
        self.add_widget(Button(
            text="World 4"
            # on_release = sm.change_screen(name="home_screen")
        ))
...
class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    ...

    def new_screen(self):
        name = "new_screen"

        # if new_screen does not exist
        if not (name in self.screen_names):
            mynewscreen = Newscreen(name=name)
            layout = MyGrids()
            mynewscreen.add_widget(layout)
            self.add_widget(mynewscreen)

        # switch screen
        self.current = name
```

## Output

[image: Add new screen]
[image: Home Screen]
[image: Switch to New Screen]

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot. I thought that was the reason but I would have never be able get out of it without your help. One more thing, why do I have to __init__ the class MyGrid?

Comment: Thank you. You are most welcome. The `__init__()` or constructor is implemented so that whenever there is an instantiation/creation of `MyGrid` object, it will construct/add the other objects automatically.